# MSAL.net or Graph SDK for backend applications

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm creating a backend service running in background without direct user interaction. It is written in .NET 4.8, and runs as a windows service.
The application will interact with a few endpoints (/users and /groups) of the Graph API, which means creating my own HttpClient is easy to do, as the number of endpoints invoked is limited.
The application should acquire an access token from Azure, based on a client secret.
I have been using the ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder and used the AcquireTokenForClient() method of Microsoft.Identity.Client namespace, to acquire a valid access token from Azure that can be used for any further calls to Graph, but the issue is, I'm not getting a refresh_token in the response of AcquireTokenForClient(), and there is no built-in refresh mechanism as far as I see?

```
        private async Task<string> AcquireAccessTokenAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("MyClientId")
                    .WithClientSecret("MyClientSecret")
                    .WithAuthority(new Uri("MyAuthority"))
                    .Build();
                var acquireResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient("RequiredScopes").ExecuteAsync();
                return acquireResult.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (MsalClientException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                throw new ApplicationException("Failed to acquire access token from Azure.");
            }
        }
```

It feels like using the Graph SDK (Graph Client) is a little overkill for the task, which is why I attempted to use the MSAL .NET library instead. But what is the right library to use when building backend services who needs an integration into Microsoft Graph? How does it support token refresh mechanism?

Comment: Using the client credentials flow doesn't use refresh tokens. If an API call fails from an expired token, [you just go get an new one and then try the call again](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#use-a-token).

Comment: @ourmandave After hours of studying the library that was my conclusion as well. And, just in case anyone are searching the same answer as I did, then the AcquireTokenForClient takes care of token cache internally, meaning that if there is a valid token in cache, it would not request a new one, until there is no valid token left in cache. Please drop an answer so I can close this question.

Comment: [It's okay to answer you own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the Client SDK furhter, and executed some test, it seems like the SDK will handle internally via a Cache, whether there is an active valid token in cache, otherwise issuing a new token request.
There is no refresh token for client Credential flows used for application services without user interaction.